# Input disabled in Bootstrap 3 typeahead

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, disabled-input, bloodhound

I'm using multiple inputs in a bootstrap modal window (which is loaded via AJAX). I want on those inputs work typeahead.js integrated with Bloodhound. The datasets are loaded correctly (as JSON), but for some reason I do not understand the inputs are automatically disabled. I'm using the latest versions of everything.

Here the inputs tag (with the related hidden input). The engine takes data-autocomplete to finish building the remote URL.

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" data-provide="typeahead" id="my_input" data-autocomplete='users'>
          <input type="hidden" name="my_input" />
```

Here my JavaScript code:

```
$.get(window.BASE_URL+'/form',function(data){
        /*SUGGESTIONS ENGINE*/
        var autocomplete;
        var autocomplete = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.id); },
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          limit: 20,
          remote: {
            url: window.BASE_URL+'the-url/',
            replace: function(url,uriEncodedQuery) {
                    if(typeof $('input:focus').attr('data-autocomplete')!='undefined')
                    {
                        var new_url=url+$('input:focus').attr('data-autocomplete')+'?texto='+$('input:focus').val()+'&tipo='+$('input:focus').attr('id');
                        return new_url;
                    }
            }
          }
        });

        autocomplete.initialize();

       //LOAD TYPEAHEADS
        $('.modal-body').find('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            minLength: 2,
            highlight:true
        },{
            name: 'autocomplete',       
            displayKey:'label',
            source: autocomplete.ttAdapter(),               
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum) {        
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
            //If the text has an id seeks its hidden twin
            if(typeof $(this).attr('id')!='undefined')
                $('input[name="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').val(datum.id);
        });
    });
```

The format of an item from the json response is as follows:

```
{"id":"1","label":"McDonald, Richard"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**:
 You should only delete the z-index property to an element.

Before:

```
.modal .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

After:

```
.modal .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: For those who use hosted bootstrap (or otherwise need to override instead of alter the original bootstrap css): `z-index: inherit`